# Connecting to an SQL database

Tags: connection, database, sql

When I am using the database connection wizard to connect to the database I type in DB server IP & credentials but it does not display any available database in list to select.  Are there some special permissions that my database user needs in order to connect to the database from the server?
[Screenshot of wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxhsL.png)

Comment: Use ODBC or SQL Server connection. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QbGoDJJuZ4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCUMS39xR8Q Need CONNECT right to `master` and conection `<database name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need CONNECT right to `master` and conection `<database name>`

Minimum right set:
`USE master
GO
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO <AccountName>
GO
USE <DataBase Name>
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO <AccountName>
GO`